# Cannot save template on Blogger

Tags: javascript, for-loop, blogger

I don't know why, but I can't save a line on blogger.

[image]

Comment: Did you read the error message? Is there something you don't understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the script. You just need to make some changes. 
There are two options :
**First:** use `&lt;` instead of `<` in `for` loop,
eg:

```
for(i=0; i &lt; functions.length; i++) {
   //rest of the code here
}
```

**Second:** wrap your code inside `// <![CDATA[ //code here ]]>`
eg:

```
// <![CDATA[

   for(i=0; i < functions.length; i++) {
     //rest of the code here
   }

// ]]>
```

Please try these and be sure to post the result if these worked or not.

Comment: @AlexB. If this answer solved your problem, feel free to click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it so.